# How do I solve this differential equation to get expression with hyperbolic tangent?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{equation}
\frac{dR(t)}{dt} = 1-R(t)-S_0 (1-R_0R(t)+\frac{R_0^2 R^2(t)}{2})
\end{equation}

I need to solve this equation to get something with $\tanh$, but when I try it in Mathematica I get another expression and I'm not able to solve this by hand.

Comment: Are you sure that the solution is a $\tanh$?, have you verified this by plugging the solution into the equation and checking if it holds? Your equation above is non linear, these equations are in general very difficult to solve.

Comment: If you know that is the behaviour of the solution perhaps you could try a substitution $R(t) = Q(t) \tanh ( a t)$ and find what $Q(t)$ and $a$ should be.

Comment: we get an ugly solution

Comment: I guess this settles whether user handles are unique. :/

Answer (score 2):

What you have is some real constants, I will call them $A,B,C,$ and
$$ R' = A R^2 + B R + C. $$
IF $$ B^2 - 4 AC > 0, $$
then there are two constant solutions, and the (bounded) solution in between them can be written in terms of $\tanh.$

EDIT, 2:30 pm Pacific. Given $B^2 - 4 AC > 0,$ define $\delta > 0$ by
$$ \color{magenta}{ \delta = \frac{1}{2} \;\sqrt {B^2 - 4AC} \; \; .}  $$
Next, define 
$$ \color{magenta}{ w = A R + \frac{B}{2} \; \; .}  $$
which gives us
$$ \color{magenta}{ w' = w^2 - \delta^2 \; \; .}  $$
**For the solutions with $- \delta < w < \delta,$ we get $w' < 0$ and** 
$$ \color{magenta}{ w = - \delta \tanh \delta t \; \; ,}  $$
finally
$$ \color{magenta}{ R = -\frac{1}{A} \left( \delta \tanh \delta t + \frac{B}{2} \right) \; \; .}  $$
Note that the system is autonomous, there is no explicit dependence on the variable  $t,$ which means that every bounded solution is a pure translate of the one above, found by replacing $t$ by $\color{magenta}{(t - t_0)}$ for some constant $t_0.$

There are also constant solutions with $|w| = \delta,$ also  some with $|w| > \delta$ that are all unbounded, those involve $\delta \coth \delta t.$

Please check the solution; the methodology is correct, but I may have made arithmetic errors.

**ORIGINAL**: Everything depends on the signs, and size, of the constants. The similar ODE
$$ y' = 1 - y^2  $$
has constant solutions with $y=1$ and $y=-1;$ in between it is tanh..

We have $$ \frac{d}{dx} \cosh x = \sinh x,$$
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \sinh x = \cosh x,$$ and
$$  \cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 x = 1.  $$

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \tanh x = \, \mbox{sech}^2 \, x,$$
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \, \mbox{sech} \, x = - \, \mbox{sech} \, x \; \tanh x,$$
$$  \tanh^2  x +  \, \mbox{sech}^2 \, x = 1.   $$

as a result, $$ 1 -  \tanh^2  x = \mbox{sech}^2 \, x. $$

So $$ y = \tanh x  $$
is a solution of $$ y' = 1 - y^2  $$
that obeys $$ -1 < y < 1.  $$

The solutions with either $y > 1$ or $y < -1$ are unbounded...
Indeed,
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \coth x = - \, \mbox{csch}^2 \, x,$$
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \, \mbox{csch} \, x = - \, \mbox{csch} \, x \; \coth x,$$
$$  \coth^2  x -  \, \mbox{csch}^2 \, x = 1,   $$
or
$$ 1 -  \coth^2  x = -  \, \mbox{csch}^2 .  $$
So, another solution to $y' = 1-y^2$ is $y = \coth x,$ which jumps across from $y < -1$ to $y > 1.$

[image]

If we switch to $$ y' = y^2 -1,   $$ all that happens is we multiply the solutions by $-1:$

[image]